# Is there an opposite command to git archive for importing zip files

Tags: git, import, zip, msysgit

Our local workflow tends to use a sequence of zip files as the local 'source control' before major revisions are formalised into the 'big' company SCM system. I'm trying to introduce git as a better local SCM method. The current workflow is quite effective for our small team, particularly as test machines are off net, as zip transfer is easy, so I need to be able to dovetail the two methods.

Is there a git command(s) that will import a project zip file and perhaps commit it?

Or is it a case of manually checking that the local working directory/branch is clean `git status`, remove all current content `git rm *`, unzip the zip file into the directory, add all `git add .`, and finally commit `git commit -a -m "filename.zip"`. We are working on Windows, so minimising opportunities for mistakes is important, so the fewer commands the better!

This will at least allow reticent existing users to decide when to make the git switch, while still getting the repo up and running.

Any suggestions on suitable commands or scripts?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have a pre-commit hook unzip the file so you add the ACTUAL source files into git, rather than an opaque zip?

Comment: @Marc: It's sort of a catch 22. No one [is using / will use] git until its has been shown to integrate with the current established work flow, so the zip files e.g. `ProjectName_V1_2_3_What_its_about.zip` are the SCM (160 of them), and I have to work with that. I has to be as easy as `dump_the_zip_into_git filename.zip` to sucker them in and get started ;-) I can tweak the few branch and merge linkages, but its too soon to attempt hooks.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might be looking for `git bundle`

Comment: @greg: `Bundle` would be right if every one had changed over to git, and the repo was cloned onto the test machine (which might not be allowed), but at the moment it needs to be able to cope with the zips we have.

Comment: @PhilipOakley : that's what I thought... sorry. It might be interesting later though, if you manage to get everyone to use git.

Comment: Just the folks at Msysgit have are now adding unzip, and gzip to the 'git for windows' package, so it should be available from the next release

Comment: You are already suggesting the best solution by yourself, IHMO. Just pack the command you named in a .bat script and you have one single command (call it `gitunzip.bat`...)

Comment: I'm slowly working on all the checks and balances that need to be in place. I was also considering whether it should be a DOS '.bat' file, or a bash '.sh' file, or a git alias - at the time the unzip methods wasn't available on the Git for Windows bash side, however it looks like the next release will have it available for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you crate a git alias for unarchive which runs all the commands you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Mark: At the time there wasn't an unzip within the msysgit version of git so it wasn't possible. Git v1.7.7 added unzip. I've still a few things to sort because the top level directory's name in the zip changes every time... (the TLD name is the version string!)