# How to construct a Git repository out of old code backups

Tags: git, zip, backup

I have quite recently started to use Git and think it is great.
Earlier I did my backups by creating a zip-package of all code and named it with the current date (e.g. "MyAndroidApp -1- 2013-03-10.zip").  That method resulted in that I stored many duplicates of a lot code.

Now I want to take these backups and create Git repository out of them.
I can't find if it is possible to set the date and time for the commit-stamp, is this possible and how?
Further more is there a simple way to commit the code from the zip-archives or do I have to unzip all of them manually, move the .git-folder and commit the code for each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Half an answer: it's easy to set the commit date (and committer, and author and author date) with `git commit`:

- `--author='A U Thor <thor@host.whatever>'`, `--date=<date>`
- set environment variables:

  - `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`: this is the `A U Thor` part above
  - `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`: this is the `thor@host.whatever` part above
  - `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`: this is the `<date>` part above
  - `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`, `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`, `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`: these are the "committer" variants of the three AUTHOR settings.

These are documented (a bit awkwardly I think) in the manual pages for `git commit`, `git config`, and `git commit-tree`.  See the one for [`git commit`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html) for date formats.

If you're unpacking things manually, there's no need to move the repo directory around, as all the git commands respect the `GIT_DIR` environment variable, so you can point to `/some/where/bare/repo.git` or whatever.

As for an automated importer, this question, [Is there an opposite command to git archive for importing zip files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7535311/1256452), is not really answered and is more than two years old, so maybe not, but I don't know.

I imagine it would be pretty easy to write a Python program to read zip files and dump them into [`git fast-import`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fast-import.html), which would be the obvious solution here.  Python already has a built-in zip-file reader.

Comment: I have considered your suggestion, and it would work for the first zip-file (initial commit), but with the second and following zip-files, I can't make a commit on all the files again, can I? I should only include the differing files in the commit written in fast-export format, how can I solve that?

Comment: According to the docs, you can emit a "delete all" command followed by "add file" for each file in the "next" zip archive.  Knowing what (little :-) ) I do about git internals, the "delete all" empties the index and then each "add" stores the blob and updates the index, so this is basically the same as you get if you "git rm" everything and re-add the next zip-file contents, which is just what is needed.

Comment: Thank you, I have now make it work. Deleting the old files before unzipping the next archive and commit the files appearing on 'git status' command.